# how to get music.listens data using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, spotify

I want to integrate spotify data to my application which is posted in Facebook.

I am tried that using Graph API Explorer by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fmusic.listens.

In order to get the brief information about individual music it takes too long time..

So can anyone help to continue this functionality in FQL..

Regards

Rajapandi

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do this using FQL. 
You need to use the Graph API and have the user_actions.music and friends_actions.music permissions.
Then you can do - graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/music.listens?access_token=

Comment: I did that way only, but it will provide some limited information. I want detailed description about the individual music like album, musician and playlist etc.. Is this possible to get those details using graph API by single request.